# one Jquery is not working on the second click

Tags: jquery

this is the code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.post_box').one('click', function(e) { 
        jQuery(this).find(".read_more").trigger("click");
    });


});
```

when I click on the div (post_box) it trigger a link (pop up greybox)located in sub div of (post_box) which has the class (read_more), right now it work good but the problem when i close the link(greybox), and click againe on the div (post_box) it doesn't work, I have to refresh the page to click it.

if i put the on() function instead , on the first click it will trigger the link and get blocked, i think it trigger the link more than one because of the sub divs 
this is the html code

```
`
<div class="post_box" >
    <div class="post_box_top">
        <div class="post_box_center">
            <div class="post_box_content">

                <div class="post_date">

                </div>
                <div class="post_content">

              <?php   echo   $content_post = get_post(get_the_ID());?>

                </div>
                <div class="post_footer">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="read_more"  rel="gb_pageset[search_sites]"  data-greybox-type="iframe">Read more</a>
               // this the link i should trigger when someone click on the <div class="post_box">   
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
```

### ec2-107-22-235-75.compute-1.amazonaws.com take a look here please, this the site with function one() in case i change to on() when you click on div it block haiders.imcserver.ro/telugu you can take a look at the second case with on() here

Comment: Please read the [faq]. Opening a second question with the same information is not the correct way to get help.

Answer (score 5):

This is correct behaviour for the `one()` method - it only binds the event once.

You need to use `on()` instead if you want the event bound for the life of the page.

```
jQuery('.post_box').on('click', function(e) { 
    jQuery(this).find(".read_more").trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: thank you for your time , but the problem when i use the on(), when i click on the link  the site block, i think because of children divs(not sure)

Answer (score 1):

You are using one, use .on() instead:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.post_box').on('click', function(e) { 
        jQuery(this).find(".read_more").trigger("click");
        return false;
    });


});
```

Comment: thank you for your time , but the problem when i use the on(), when i click on the link the site block, i think because of children divs(not sure)

Comment: Edit your question and post relevant html code. How can i help you if i dont know what are you talking about...

Comment: I put the live site in case you want to take a look

Comment: I see you are using mansonry plugin, this seems to interfer with your expected behaviour, or more probably the greybox one plugin. Where is set the .read_more click handler?