# Jquery function doesn't work on the second click

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [one Jquery is not working on the second click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197404/one-jquery-is-not-working-on-the-second-click)

this is the code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.post_box').one('click', function(e) { 
        jQuery(this).find(".read_more").trigger("click");
    });


});
```

when I click on the div (post_box) it trigger a link (pop up greybox)located in sub div of (post_box) which has the class (read_more), right now it work good but the problemwhen i close the link(greybox), and click againe on the div (post_box) it doesn't work, I have to refresh the page to click it.

if i put the on() function instead , on the first click it will trigger the link and get blocked, i think it trigger the link more than one because of the sub divs this is the html code

```
<div class="post_box" >
    <div class="post_box_top">
        <div class="post_box_center">
            <div class="post_box_content">

                <div class="post_date">

                </div>
                <div class="post_content">

              <?php   echo   $content_post = get_post(get_the_ID());?>

                </div>
                <div class="post_footer">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="read_more"  rel="gb_pageset[search_sites]"  data-greybox-type="iframe">Read more</a>
               // this the link i should trigger when someone click on the <div class="post_box">   
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please take a look

ec2-107-22-235-75.compute-1.amazonaws.com take a look here please, this the site with function one() in case i change to on() when you click on div it block haiders.imcserver.ro/telugu you can take a look at the second case with on() here

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/one/ […] The handler is executed at most once per element.

Comment: What do you mean by `get blocked`?

Comment: Please make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate the issue you're having.

Comment: I mean when user click on the <div class=post_box>, it should pop up a greybox of a post , in the case i use the one() function it work for just one click , in the case i use the on() function when user click on the div it pop up and the the site block i mean the browser make restart.

Comment: http://ec2-107-22-235-75.compute-1.amazonaws.com take a look here please, this the site with function one() in case i change to on() when you click on div it block http://haiders.imcserver.ro/telugu you can take a look at the second case with on() here

Comment: Sorry for duplicate the subject it the first time i use this site

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) not [`.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one). `on` binds the event, `one` binds the event to be executed once per element.

Comment: if i put the on() function instead , on the first click it will trigger the link and get blocked, i think it trigger the link more than one because of the sub divs this is the html code

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use click function:

```
$(function(){
    $('.post_box').click(function(e) { 
        $(".read_more").trigger("click");
    });
});
```